# DPY-4011: the database or network closed the connection

Tags: connection-string, python-oracledb

I am using Oracle 11.2.0, Python 3.10.3

I am trying to connect to a Infor Oracle database with the following script:

```
import oracledb
TEST="'xxxx':'XXX'/'XXX'"
with oracledb.connect(user="xxx", password="xxx", dsn=TEST, disable_oob=True)
```

it return:

```
oracledb.exceptions.DatabaseError: DPY-4011: the database or network closed the connection
```

could you help me?

Comment: What version of python-oracledb are you using? What database version are you using? What platform? Can you show the output when setting the environment variable ``PYO_DEBUG_PACKETS`` to any value? Without some of that information I can't help you!